# How to display ec2 instances details from multiple regions using single command, in my case from us-east-1 and us-west-1?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I am trying to get instance-id, availability zone, instance status, instance name(from tags) of ec2 instances hosted in us-east-1 and us-west-1 region in a single AWS CLI command so that I can export the output in an excel file.

I can get the output from one region at a time using the below commands but couldn't find a way to get the output from two regions using one single command.

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --region us-east-1 --query Reservations[].Instances[].{ID:InstanceId,State:State.Name,AZ:Placement.AvailabilityZone,TagName:Tags[0].Value} --output text>C:\Users\PiyushVermaVerma\Desktop\testfile.xls
```

and:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --region us-west-1 --query Reservations[].Instances[].[InstanceId,Tags[0].Value,Placement.AvailabilityZone,State.Name] --output text>C:\Users\PiyushVermaVerma\Desktop\testfile.xls
```

Answer (score 3):

In Bash, it is not possible to specify more than one region but you can always do this:

```sh
for region in us-east-1 us-west-1 ; do
  aws ec2 describe-instances --query \
    'Reservations[*].Instances[*].{ID:InstanceId,State:State.Name,AZ:Placement.AvailabilityZone,TagName:Tags[0].Value}' \
  --output text --region $region
done > C:\Users\PiyushVermaVerma\Desktop\testfile.xls
```

For Windows Batch, you are probably best off just running the two commands in sequence, and using the [append](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~r92092/ref/win32/win32scripting.html#Win32Scripting-Command-Redirection-And-Pipelines) `>>` operator:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --region us-east-1 --query Reservations[].Instances[].{ID:InstanceId,State:State.Name,AZ:Placement.AvailabilityZone,TagName:Tags[0].Value} --output text > C:\Users\PiyushVermaVerma\Desktop\testfile.xls
aws ec2 describe-instances --region us-east-1 --query Reservations[].Instances[].{ID:InstanceId,State:State.Name,AZ:Placement.AvailabilityZone,TagName:Tags[0].Value} --output text >> C:\Users\PiyushVermaVerma\Desktop\testfile.xls
```

Comment: Alex, thank you for the quick response, I tried the above mentioned command but I am getting the error message "region was unexpected at this time".

Comment: The above code will work with Linux, but the OP appears to be using Windows.

Comment: Yes, I have assumed you are using the Bash shell because AWS CLI on PowerShell has different syntax. I'll provide Batch syntax in a sec.

Answer (score 1):

You can only list instances in one region at a time.

Each region is a collection of zones. You are connecting to each region to list instances in the zones within that region. These zones are data centers and most are fairly large.

You will need to iterate thru each region.